# Usage of "keep from"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrasal-verbs

I want to express that something prevents somebody to do an activity. Is a proper way to use **keep from**? Is there another suitable synonym?

When I use it in the sentence, is it correct?

> Nothing had kept you from uploading before the deadline came.

I am still improving my English, benevolence please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example sentence is actually really good. The only thing I would change would be using the verb "to **arrive**" instead of "to **come**", like so:

> Nothing had kept you from uploading before the deadline **arrived**.

I'll note, however, that if you want to say that something prevented someone from doing something else, then the example you have actually represents the opposite, that *nothing* prevented this person from doing something. You can simply replace "Nothing" with whatever *did* prevent that person.

But yes, "**keep from**" is the proper verb to use, and you're using it correctly.